# Best way to present a long Segmented Picker in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, picker

I need some suggestions on presenting a segmented picker in Swift UI.

It is to display distinct time ranges (<15min, <30min, <45min) all the way to 120min.

It ends up being 8 segments.  I am really not a fan of the scrolling picker as it not in theme what what I am looking for in presentation.

The problem with how it stands now is that the time unit is cut off with each segment showing "15.." and doesn't look clean.

I have put the segmented picker in a horizontal scroll view which looks okay but the user may not know to scroll.

One option I used but can't get to work out is splitting the one long segment into 2 separate views.

The problem is the user can select a segment from either pickers which is not what I want.

What I want is if the user selects one picker, the other one is not selectable or vice versa.

I have been messing with some formatting options, so please ignore that.

Is this possible?

Thanks is advance!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack{

                To60min()
                To120min()
            
             .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        }
    }}


    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }}
  
struct To60min: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTimeRangeto60 = ""
    @State private var timeRangesTo60 = ["15min", "30min", "45min", "60min"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("", selection: $selectedTimeRangeto60) {
            ForEach(timeRangesTo60, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
                       }
                   }
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: 75)
            .background(.gray)
                   .padding()
                   .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                   .contrast(22.0)
        }
}

struct To120min: View {
    
    @State private var selectedTimeRangeto120 = ""
    @State private var timeRangesTo120 = ["75min", "90min", "105min", "120min"]

    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("", selection: $selectedTimeRangeto120) {
            ForEach(timeRangesTo120, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .contrast(22)
    }
}
```

[image: not what I Want :(]

Comment: I would stay with one picker in scroller, probably just add some leading/trailing indicators (buttons) that show that there are more there. Braking in two ... weird idea, IMO.

Comment: Since the units are all just minutes, how about having text explaining choose time in minutes and have the picker only show the numbers?

Comment: Although not recommended, this is possible.  If you bind both pickers to the same value, then when one updates the other will change.  Since the values of the pickers are disjoint, only one value will show in a picker at a time.

Comment: You can always just create your own picker with a grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything more than 3-4 items (depending on label length), I would switch from a `.segmented` to `.menu` picker style. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pickerstyle